# does calling delete on an object pointer recursively delete its dynamically allocated members

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

If I have a class A that contains a dynamically allocated instance of class B, does calling delete on a pointer to an instance of A (received from new of course) also effectively deallocate the memory occupied by the instance of B? Or does the destructor of A have to explicitly call delete on the instance of B in order for that to happen?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on how you're storing the pointer to `B` within the `A` type.

```
class B;

class A {
private:
    SomePointer m_b;
};
```

What is `SomePointer`?

- If it's `B*` then no, deletion of this `B` allocation is *not* automatic. You would need to implement the destructor `A::~A()` and delete it there.  Don't forget to delete/implement the copy/move construction/assignment functions as well, or a copy/move operation will result in two `A`s owning the same `B` and that leads to (among other things) the double-free problem.
- If it's `std::unique_ptr<B>` then congratulations, you made the right choice and you don't have to do anything. `A`'s implicitly-defined destructor will destroy the `std::unique_ptr<B>` which will delete the allocated `B` for you.  Additionally, the move constructor/assignment functions will be implicitly defined correctly (assuming the rest of the data members of `A` are movable) and `A`'s copy operations will be implicitly deleted as they would be ill-formed (`std::unique_ptr<B>` is not copyable).

Here's an example of the two approaches.  They both allow the same operations on `A`.  First, using a raw pointer:

```
class A {
public:
    A();

    // Need custom move logic.
    A(A &&);
    A & operator=(A &&);

    // Prevent copying.
    A(A const &) = delete;
    A & operator=(A const &) = delete;

    ~A();

private:
    B * m_b;
};

A::A() : m_b{nullptr} { }

A::~A() { delete m_b; }

A::A(A && other) : A{} { *this = std::move(other); }

A & A::operator=(A && other) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(m_b, other.m_b);
    return *this;
}
```

Now using `std::unique_ptr<B>`:

```
class A {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
}
```

Which one would you rather maintain?  Which one is easier to get right?

Comment: Thanks! Quick follow up does the implicit destructor call the destructors of member objects?

Comment: @HashBr0wn Yes. An explicitly-declared destructor will also do so; you can't prevent a destructor from calling the destructor of any sub-objects. An explicitly-defined destructor is for doing anything _extra_ that may need to be done beyond destroying sub-objects.